# How to split string with regular expression?

Tags: regex, nginx

In nginx i want to handle argumet looks like:

```
1530569.52624839870259166,524135.21126760687911883,1531064.27656850102357566,524629.96158770937472582
```

So four numbers separated by comma. I want to parse it and get separated numbers.
I can get first number use:

```
^([^,]+)
```

How can i get another numbers?

Comment: You should explain how you intend to process these separate numbers within Nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you always have four fixed CSV numbers, then you may try the following pattern:

```
^([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)$
```

The four numbers would then be available as four separate capture groups.

Most regex engines do not store repeating capture groups, so though we might be tempted to use the following pattern, it also might not work:

```
^([^,]+)(,[^,]+){3}$
```

**Edit:**

If what you're after is separate regex patterns for each number, then maybe this would help:

```
first:  ^([^,]+)
second: ^[^,]+,([^,]+)
third:  ^[^,]+,[^,]+,([^,]+)
fourth: ^[^,]+(?:,[^,]+){2},([^,]+)
```

Comment: tried your solution but it return all numbers. I want to get separatelly first, second, 3th and 4th numbers. I mean only one number at time.

Comment: @KliverMax Not sure what you are after here...I updated my answer with four separate patterns.